# Stop animation function when another one starts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

There are two different functions, one for `mouseenter` and one for `mouseleave`.

The first one shows the block, the second hides it (both with animation).

The problem is, `mouseleave` can be started before the animation inside `mouseenter` finishes.

In this case, the block blinks several times.

I would like to stop any animation inside `mouseenter` function, when `mouseleave` starts.

How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place a `.stop()` in front of each of your animation functions. E.g:

```
$(this).stop().slideDown();
$(this).stop().slideUp();
```

If `$(this)` is not currently animating, `.stop()` will simply do nothing.

---

**Note:** You may experience problems with the standard slide and fade functions when used with `.stop()` - these remember the last height/opacity the element fully animated to. So if the element only reached 50% height before a `.stop().slideUp()` was called, the next `.slideDown()` will cause it to animate to only 50% height. See this happening [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Stwnv/1/) by moving your mouse quickly in and out, before entering again.

The jQuery documentation suggests using `.stop(true, true)` which causes half-completed animations to jump to their final position. This of course creates an unsightly "flash".

I suggest avoiding `.slideUp()` or `.fadeIn()` completely and setting a specific height/opacity to animate to, e.g:

```
$(this).stop().animate({height: 100});
$(this).stop().animate({height: 0});
```

See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Stwnv/.